# How should I chain HTTPHandler with RotatingFileHandler in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I needed to create a system, where log messages generated in an embedded system are logged remotely on a server and stored in the rotated log files. Due to restrictions in network communication, the log messages had to be transported via HTTP protocol. The server runs already a [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) based HTTP server, and therefore I wanted to integrate the logging system with Flask-based web applicattion.

The Python [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module offers the dedicated [`HTTPhandler`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler) class for that purpose. Basing on the `logging` documentation, I have created the first implementation.

The server part:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Response
from flask import request
import logging
import logging.handlers
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'logging server'

@app.route('/log', methods=['POST'])
def handle_log():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       rd=request.form.to_dict()
       record = logging.makeLogRecord(rd)
       log1.handle(record)
       return "OK"

log1=logging.getLogger('MTEST')
log1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('logs','a',maxBytes=10000000,backupCount=10)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
rfh.setFormatter(formatter)
log1.addHandler(rfh)
log1.error("First error generated locally")
app.run()
```

The client part:

```
import logging, logging.handlers
myLogger = logging.getLogger('MTEST')
myLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
httpHandler = logging.handlers.HTTPHandler('localhost:5000',url='/log',method="POST")
myLogger.addHandler(httpHandler)

myLogger.info('Small info message')
myLogger.debug('Small debug message')
myLogger.erro('Small error message')
```

However, with that implementation the server reported the following errors (I copied one of four almost identical error messages) and only the locally generated error message was logged.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 76, in emit
    if self.shouldRollover(record):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 156, in shouldRollover
    msg = "%s\n" % self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 741, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 465, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 329, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I have added printing of the form data transmitted to the server and the attributes of the created LogRecord object. It appeared, that the `args` attribute is transmitted as empty tupple and not created.
To cure that I have modified the `handle_log` routine:

```
@app.route('/log', methods=['POST'])
def handle_log():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       rd=request.form.to_dict()
       rd['args']=""
       record = logging.makeLogRecord(rd)
       log1.handle(record)
       return "OK"
```

Logging still wasn't working, but the errors produced by the server have changed:

```
Logged from file test1.py, line 9
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2018 23:52:51] "POST /log HTTP/1.0" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 76, in emit
    if self.shouldRollover(record):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 156, in shouldRollover
    msg = "%s\n" % self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 741, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 467, in format
    record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 423, in formatTime
    ct = self.converter(record.created)
TypeError: a float is required
```

To check, what is wrong, I have added the filter printing the created LogRecord object:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Response
from flask import request
import logging
import logging.handlers
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'logging server'

@app.route('/log', methods=['POST'])
def handle_log():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       rd=request.form.to_dict()
       rd['args']=""
       record = logging.makeLogRecord(rd)
       log1.handle(record)
       return "OK"

class myflt(logging.Filter):
  def filter(self,rec):
    print(rec.__dict__)
    return 1

log1=logging.getLogger('MTEST')
log1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
rfh=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('logs','a',maxBytes=10000000,backupCount=10)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
rfh.setFormatter(formatter)
log1.addHandler(rfh)
log1.addFilter(myflt())
log1.error("First error generated locally")
app.run()
```

After that, I could compare the LogRecord objects created for the locally generated message:

```
{'threadName': 'MainThread', 'name': 'MTEST', 'thread': 139678016341824, 'created': 1531259894.112536, 'process': 5595, 'processName': 'MainProcess', 'args': (), 'module': 'srv1', 'filename': 'srv1.py', 'levelno': 40, 'exc_text': None, 'pathname': 'srv1.py', 'lineno': 37, 'msg': 'First error generated locally', 'exc_info': None, 'funcName': '<module>', 'relativeCreated': 44.27504539489746, 'levelname': 'ERROR', 'msecs': 112.53595352172852}
```

And for the remotely generated message:

```
{'relativeCreated': u'12.3879909515', 'process': u'5597', 'module': u'test1', 'funcName': u'<module>', 'filename': u'test1.py', 'levelno': u'10', 'processName': u'MainProcess', 'lineno': u'9', 'msg': u'Small debug message', 'args': '', 'exc_text': u'None', 'name': u'MTEST', 'thread': u'140221336438592', 'created': u'1531259898.51', 'threadName': u'MainThread', 'msecs': u'511.312007904', 'pathname': u'test1.py', 'exc_info': u'None', 'levelname': u'DEBUG'}
```

It appears, that the transmission of the log record via `HTTPHandler` converts all numbers into strings, and therefore the `makeLogRecord` function is not able to correctly recreate the `LogRecord` object in the server.

What is the proper way to transmit the log messages via `HTTPHandler` so that they may be properly handled by e.g., `RotatingFileHandler` in a remote machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found something, that seems to be a viable workaround.
The dictionary with atributes of the `LogRecord` object created in the client is converted to JSON before passing to the server. The server then decodes it and recreates the original `LogRecord`.

The server part:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Response
from flask import request
import logging
import logging.handlers
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'logging server'

@app.route('/log', methods=['POST'])
def handle_log():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       rd=request.form.to_dict()
       rec=json.loads(rd['record'])
       record = logging.makeLogRecord(rec)
       log1.handle(record)
       return "OK"

class myflt(logging.Filter):
  def filter(self,rec):
    print(rec.__dict__)
    return 1

mfl=myflt()

log1=logging.getLogger('MTEST')
log1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
rfh=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('logs','a',maxBytes=10000000,backupCount=10)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
rfh.setFormatter(formatter)
log1.addHandler(rfh)
log1.addFilter(mfl)
log1.error("First error generated locally")
app.run()
```

The client part:

```
import logging, logging.handlers
import json

class myHTTPHandler(logging.handlers.HTTPHandler):
  def mapLogRecord(self,record):
    trec={'record':json.dumps(record.__dict__)}
    return trec

myLogger = logging.getLogger('MTEST')
myLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
httpHandler = myHTTPHandler('localhost:5000',url='/log',method="POST")
myLogger.addHandler(httpHandler)

myLogger.info('Small info message')
myLogger.debug('Small debug message')
myLogger.error('Small error message')
```

The above implementation works correctly, however it seems to be unnecessarily complicated.
Is there any simpler way to use `HTTPHandler` to communicate with the remote `RotatingFileHandler` via HTTP protocol?