# Python, How should I log errors from multiple subprocesses?

Tags: python, logging

I need to implement in Python a "supervisor" process that starts multiple subprocesses, and monitors their operation. One of tasks that must be solved is logging of error messages generated by them.
After reading that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953835/run-subprocess-and-print-output-to-logging/21978778#21978778) I have found the following solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import subprocess
import threading
import time

import logging, logging.handlers

def log_subprocess_output(pipe):
    with pipe:
      for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''): # b'\n'-separated lines
        myLogger.info('got line from subprocess: %r', line)
    myLogger.info("Leaving output handler")

myLogger = logging.getLogger('MTEST')
myLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
myHandler = logging.FileHandler('log.txt')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
myHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
myLogger.addHandler(myHandler)

myLogger.info('Test info message')
myLogger.debug('Test debug message')
myLogger.error('Test error message')
npar=[["test1","1.5","10"], 
      ["test2","1.3","20"],
      ["test3","0.8","30"]]
for pars in npar:
  # Let's start the external application
  cmd=["./ext.py",]+pars
  pd=subprocess.Popen(cmd,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  # Now we should start the thread (process?) reading the stderr
  th=threading.Thread(target=log_subprocess_output,args=(pd.stderr,))
  th.start()
```

Where the external application generates programmable number of artifficial error messages with programmable period:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time
period=float(sys.argv[2])
number=int(sys.argv[3])
for i in range(0,number):
   time.sleep(period)
   sys.stderr.write(sys.argv[1]+" "+str(i)+'\n')
```

The presented solution works reliably (I have even tested it with HTTP connected remote logging server presented in that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274534/how-should-i-chain-httphandler-with-rotatingfilehandler-in-python)).
However, I dislike it due to the necessity to mix [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) modules. Is there any better solution for logging error messages from subprocesses?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why threading is needed is because the output from the child process can fill up its output buffers, which would cause it to block and thus never terminate, nor do its work. Your process is presumably busy doing other stuff, so you have to spin up a thread to read the output from the child process in the background, while your process does other work.

If you didn't have useful work to do while the child process chugs away in the background, you could just call `pd.communicate()`, which reads the output (using threads, but under the hood) , waits for the child process and then returns the output to you.

Comment: I need to start multiple subprocesses in parallel (because I'm writing a "supervisor") and monitor their stderr. That's why I can't use pd.communicate().

Comment: @wzab Sure, I understand. I was just giving the reason why you won't be able to avoid threads.